# How to assign 50% of participants to one survey and 50% to another

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am using the "Survey Link" template to create a project on Mechanical Turk.

I am running an A/B test. I would like to direct 50% of workers to one link, and 50% to another link.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the "Design Layout" page, click on "Source". This will let you edit the html/javascript/css for the survey.

You'll find a `<table>` element with a `<tbody>` element. Change the `<tbody>` element to this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="survey-one">
        <td><label>Survey link:</label></td>
        <td><a class="dont-break-out" href="http://link-to-survey-1">http://link-to-survey-1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="survey-two">
        <td><label>Survey link:</label></td>
        <td><a class="dont-break-out" href="http://link-to-survey-2">http://link-to-survey-2</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This simply adds another row to the table for the link for your second survey. Note the `link-to-survey-1` and `link-to-survey-2` that you'll need to replace with your own links.

A bit lower in the file, you'll see the `<style>` element. Add this to it:

```
.survey-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

And a bit lower, you'll see a `<script>` element. At the bottom of it, right before the `});`, add the following javascript:

```
var surveyToHide = (Math.random() >= 0.5) ? '.survey-one' : '.survey-two';
$(surveyToHide).addClass('survey-hidden');
```

This randomly picks one of your suveys, and makes it hidden, so that the worker sees only one.